# Locating Electrical Outlet Behind Kitchen Cabinet?

Tags: electrical, wiring, kitchens

I'm currently trying to install an over the range microwave, but I realized that the contractor likely put up a my kitchen cabinets over the outlet itself. Without having to remove the entire cabinet or pulling out the entire back panel, is there a good way to locate the outlet?

I've seen some recommendations for a stud finder with AC detection or a non-contact voltage tester, but wanted to check if someone had any insight into this issue. Thanks so much!

Comment: If you have either of those tools, go ahead and try. I would not hold my breath, but they might work.

Comment: Why do you suspect a hidden outlet, Any knowledgeable responsible  contractor would know it is against code to bury an outlet.

Comment: @AlaskaMan Unfortunately there are far too many contractors who don't fall into the categories of "knowledgeable" and "responsible".

Comment: Was there a microwave there previously ? Was the previous microwave part of the range ?

Comment: Thanks all! Yes, @blacksmith37, I can see an outline of a microwave there previously.

Comment: And @jwh20, yeah, let's say our apartment contractors are not the best.

Comment: But you can't say for sure the previous microwave wasn't part of an "all-in-one" with a previous range/oven.  How recently were these cabinets put in? Are you in an apartment, and if so could you inspect a similar apartment on another floor or hall?

Comment: I would use a stud finder with voltage detection. If the receptacle is at the end of a run you can get close. An example the run comes down from the ceiling and stops you have a target area. However if the cable comes down and continues down to another receptacle the stud finder may not work but could get you close. Do you have any photos of the outlet location? They are usually attached to a stud if installed as new construction but if it was added later it may be in an old work box not connected to a stud these usually are on a feed that stops at the receptacle.